# Rotate UIImageView inside UIScrollView get X and Y inverted. Why?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code, which makes my image rotate, scale and pan to positioning it on screen.

The problem is, when I rotate the image more than 90º, the X and Y are inverted. i.e. if I move left, the image goes up and if I move to right, the image goes down. But when image is at 0º I can move it normally.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgLogo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollLogo: UIScrollView!

    var identity = CGAffineTransform.identity

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupLayout()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
    }

    func setupLayout(){
    
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(scale))
        let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotate))
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(positioningImage))

        pinchGesture.delegate = self
        rotationGesture.delegate = self
        panGesture.delegate = self

        view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    @objc func scale(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            identity = imgLogo.transform
        case .changed,.ended:
            imgLogo.transform = identity.scaledBy(x: gesture.scale, y: gesture.scale)
        case .cancelled:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    @objc func rotate(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        imgLogo.transform = imgLogo.transform.rotated(by: gesture.rotation)
    }

    @objc func positioningImage(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let points = gesture.translation(in: scrollLogo)
    
        imgLogo.transform = imgLogo.transform.translatedBy(x: points.x, y: points.y)

        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: scrollLogo)
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Can someone help me indicate what is wrong? Where/how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: “Can someone help me indicate what is wrong?” Nothing.  If you rotate with a transform you are changing the entire coordinate system. So the x and y axes are rotated; that is what a transform is. So if you translate along the x axis now, you move in the direction that the x axis points now. That is what `transform.translatedBy(x: points.x, y: points.y)` does. It translates in terms of the already existing rotation transform.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but i dont understand what you mean. How to rotate to work like it should be?

Answer (score 1):

Your panning is currently relative to `scrollLogo`, if you change the points declaration to

```
let points = gesture.translation(in: imgLogo)
```

then the panning will be done relative to the image’s current translation, and it should work as intended!

Comment: Thank you!!!! Is there all the time rsrsrrs thanks for your hawk eye rsrsrrs